# Silverlight BusyIndicator

Tags: silverlight

Is there a way to not show the BusyIndicator when it is not busy (IsBusy='false')?  After I added the silverlight BusyIndicator into my UserControl it uses a large area so all other controls are moved down and the GUI looks not good anymore.  I need it is hided when it's no busy and shows up when it's busy.

Thanks for help.

CK

Comment: can you show some more code of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2):

I would use a standard BooleanToVisiblityConverter and bind the Visibilty to the IsBusy property like such:

```
    <Grid Height="500" Width="500"  Background="Blue">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Converters:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Width="75">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="BusyButton" Content="Toggle Busy State"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ProgressButton" Content="Toggle ProgressButton State"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator Grid.Row="1" IsBusy="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=BusyButton}"
                           Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Width="120" Height="10" Margin="4 2" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsIndeterminate="True"
                 Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ProgressButton, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
</Grid>
```

I've provided both a BusyIndicator as well as ProgressBar is this example so you can see both in action.

The BooleanToVisibilityConverter is pretty standard and is implemented as such:

```
    public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
{
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;

            return (bool)value == true ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
}
```