# Silverlight DataGrid is null after loaded event in ChildWindow

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Here's the XAML structure. You'll see below that I'm subscribing to the Loaded event of the grid. But when the even fires, `this.selectionGrid` is still `null` - even in consequent layout updates it is still `null`, even though I can see the grid all populated.

I do use MEFedMVVM and MvvmLight, but I don't see how it relates to this situation.

Any ideas why?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter
                    Visibility="{Binding Path=CurrentStep,Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="Select Equipment" Style="{StaticResource HeaderBlockStyle}" /> 
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                        <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="selectionGrid" GridLinesVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableEquipmentView}" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" 
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" LayoutUpdated="selectionGrid_LayoutUpdated" Loaded="selectionGrid_Loaded" LoadingRowGroup="selectionGrid_LoadingRowGroup">
```

Comment: Questions: Are you missing some xaml? Why is content inside a BusyIndicator? Why are you defining content inside the ContentPresenter

Comment: Yeah my XAML is huge - I just wanted to give a sense of the structure. Putting controls in a BusyIndicator is something I do often, when you set IsBusy, then all child controls are disabled - which helps. It is in a ContentPresenter, because I have several different views that I'm bringing up in wizard type scenario, as you might observe the Visibility binding there.

Comment: The standard behavior of the BusyIndicator is to "disable" items. Just place it at the end of your xaml, no need to put items in it. See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012870/silverlight-busyindicator/9014486#9014486. That's not how ContentPresenters are intended to be used. They are intended to present content from it's Content property.

Comment: It was the ContentPresenter causing the issue. I swapped it to a Grid and voila! - it now works. Thanks a lot for the help. Please create an answer, so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the ContentPresenter. ContentPresenter are intended to display their Content property and not "manual" children.

I would also mention that you do not need to place controls into the BusyIndicator. The BusyIndicator will fill all available space so place it at the "bottom" of the Grid (below all other controls in xaml)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=CurrentStep,Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Select Equipment" Style="{StaticResource HeaderBlockStyle}" /> 
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="selectionGrid" GridLinesVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="White" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableEquipmentView}" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" 
                          LayoutUpdated="selectionGrid_LayoutUpdated" Loaded="selectionGrid_Loaded" 
                          LoadingRowGroup="selectionGrid_LoadingRowGroup">
    <! -- Other controls -->
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
</Grid>
```